# Why on earth is not this return statement executed here in my codesandbox UseEffect

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval, use-effect

I learn React JavaScript and have this [Sandbox to play around](https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-hotpink-loader-jscp9?file=/src/PromiseLoader.js:418-426)

As you see here in PromiseLoader.js

[image]

The `return` inside the `useEffect` has a `console.log(..` that never firers why is that?
I thought the JavaScript `setInterval` asynchronous?

Comment: Well useEffect turn's you a function so at some point you need to call the function. Do you?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you return from `useEffect` is called when React performs cleanup.

From https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt out of this behavior in case it creates performance issues later below.

Check out this modified sandbox to see it in effect: https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-hotpink-loader-forked-xujbl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Click on the button to show/hide the Promise Loader component. Notice when you hide the component, it unmounts, and console.log shows that the cleanup function is indeed being executed.